# RoR / RSpec request cookie change not persisting when changed in test case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to test that refreshing a user session works (using JWT web tokens). The server passes back an access cookie to be used for web and after hitting the refresh endpoint I am trying to set the request cookie to be the response cookie, and then making another request to validate that the new access cookie is valid.

The issue that I am facing is that despite setting the request cookie to the response cookie before making the next request it still uses the old request cookie (which is expired).

This is the test case:

```rb
it 'maintains a users session' do
        JWTSessions.access_exp_time = 0

        external_sign_in(identifier: user.mobile_number, password: 'password', client: :web)

        JWTSessions.access_exp_time = 3600

        puts request.cookies[JWTSessions.access_cookie]
        post :refresh

        request.cookies[JWTSessions.access_cookie] = response.cookies['jwt_access']
        request.headers[JWTSessions.csrf_header] = response_json['csrf']

        puts '======='
        puts response.cookies['jwt_access']
        puts request.cookies[JWTSessions.access_cookie]
        puts '======='
        get :index

        puts request.cookies[JWTSessions.access_cookie]
        expect(response_json['message']).to include(user.first_name)
      end
```

Context: externa_sign_in is a helper method that sets the correct csrf header and request cookie when the client is :web.

Output from the put statements:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NjY3NTk5MzgsInVzZXJfaWQiOjIxNjYsInVpZCI6Ijc3NmIwYTIyLWI3ZWUtNDhmYy1hYWIzLWM5MTMyZGQ2ZDAyZiIsImV4cCI6MTU2Njc1OTkzOCwicnVpZCI6IjkzM2RmMTZjLWYwZjYtNDlmYy1hYWZhLTk5MmE2NjhmMTk3YyJ9.SWPGjSKzJVbCr7cBTFiAZieLOfgLnNWTjKfY2w3LTZc
=======
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NjY3NjM1MzgsImV4cCI6MTU2Njc2MzUzOCwidXNlcl9pZCI6MjE2NiwidWlkIjoiNzAwNTdhODQtN2MzNC00M2M2LWE4MzYtZjI0ODIxNTdlM2Y2IiwicnVpZCI6IjkzM2RmMTZjLWYwZjYtNDlmYy1hYWZhLTk5MmE2NjhmMTk3YyJ9.0lkiJ9Iu3R3NHSg0RsGzoSh2rVhwGnp5X0ZYS2jvncQ
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NjY3NjM1MzgsImV4cCI6MTU2Njc2MzUzOCwidXNlcl9pZCI6MjE2NiwidWlkIjoiNzAwNTdhODQtN2MzNC00M2M2LWE4MzYtZjI0ODIxNTdlM2Y2IiwicnVpZCI6IjkzM2RmMTZjLWYwZjYtNDlmYy1hYWZhLTk5MmE2NjhmMTk3YyJ9.0lkiJ9Iu3R3NHSg0RsGzoSh2rVhwGnp5X0ZYS2jvncQ
=======
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NjY3NTk5MzgsInVzZXJfaWQiOjIxNjYsInVpZCI6Ijc3NmIwYTIyLWI3ZWUtNDhmYy1hYWIzLWM5MTMyZGQ2ZDAyZiIsImV4cCI6MTU2Njc1OTkzOCwicnVpZCI6IjkzM2RmMTZjLWYwZjYtNDlmYy1hYWZhLTk5MmE2NjhmMTk3YyJ9.SWPGjSKzJVbCr7cBTFiAZieLOfgLnNWTjKfY2w3LTZc
```

Also it seems like the csrf header updates, so not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to do `cookies.delete(...)` before setting the cookie again. Not sure why, but it seems to fix it.